# powershell script to mass unique password per file/folder

Tags: powershell, encryption, passwords

So I need to uniquely assign a different password to 240 files on 150 usb's.

If there is a powershell script or third party software that any of you know of?

Obviously I wouldn't be doing 150 usb's at once (if you know of a deployment I could do that to a computer lab, assuming every computer would assign the usb's the same letter/s)

30 groups of 5 students, So I would be doing 5 at a time. Those five would be the same encryption, just 8 different files with 8 different passwords.

Comment: Frame challenge: why not put the data on a (intranet) web server instead? Encrypt the files and send passwords to each student group. Or use server's ACLs to limit which students can download the files, so no need to encrypt at all?

Comment: What do you mean with 'assigning a password to a file'? You can password protect a compressed folder, but you can't password protect a file/folder in native Windows. If you are in an Active Directory where each student has a unique user and password, you can use ACL to protect those files/folders. In a certain way they are also 'password protected' then.

Comment: Also what is the use of 150 USB keys? Can't you use a different approach? USB keys and security aren't really a match. Also, it looks like your question is not really a PowerShell question, but more a question for SuperUser/ServerFault.

Comment: @vonPryz
We aren't wanting to use a online system due to the needs of the students involved. 

We know that the content we will put on the usb's will be difficult to download by some of the students. Their internet is quite poor.

Comment: @ITM 
The plan is to have an interactive experience through this new world order, I apologize for saying files, I meant folders. The activity is intended to be an escape room type experience, activity one will be password protected and the password would be sent to them after they complete said puzzle. (folder 1). Then activity two similar - complete puzzle, then password given for folder 2. I would have to research ACL, thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

This piqued my interest, so here's an idea. Tie password to volume label. Sure, it's trivial to check out, but at least one needs both the USB and the file. And since it's an escape room -styled puzzle, maybe it shouldn't be too hard either.

First, create an alias to 7-Zip, wich is used to compress and encrypt files. Then get volume serial number via WMI. The sample looks for C drive's serial, so change that into whatever letter your USB uses. Then invoke the actual compression. Like so,

```
Set-Alias sz 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'
$key=(Get-WmiObject -query "select volumeserialnumber from Win32_logicaldisk where name ='c:'").VolumeSerialNumber.insert(4, '-')  
invoke-command { sz $args } -argumentlist @("a", "-p$key", "-tzip", "supersecret.zip", "secrets\*")
```

This can be written as a function, so each time you are done with an USB, call the function again.